# Award full bounty for auto awarded question

Tags: support, bounties

I went out of town this weekend and was unexpectedly without an Internet connection and [my question's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3570573/how-should-i-create-a-rest-api-using-rails-3-0) bounty expired, awarding only half of the bounty to the highest answer (which is in the FAQ and I completely understand).

However, I fully intended to award that user with the full amount, is there a way that I can do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, unfortunately, once bounties are awarded, they cannot be modified or reversed in any way or form. The only option available is to start another bounty on the question.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the answer :-)